# Bootstrap Typeahead with AJAX source: not returning array as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am having a lot of trouble getting bootstraps typeahead to work properly with an AJAX source.

If I alert out the array that is being returned it is perfectly fine, even when I hard code it to test it. It seems to return nothing most of the time or only a few items from the array when you have typed in a near match.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
$('#companyNameInput').typeahead({
      source: function(query, process){

          $.ajax({
            url: ROOT+'Record/checkCompanyName',
            async: false,
            data: 'q='+query,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
              companiesFinal = [];
              map = {};
              companies = $.parseJSON(data);
              $.each(companies, function(i, v){
                map[v.name] = v.id;
                companiesFinal.push(v.name);
              })
            }
          })
          process(companiesFinal);

          // return ['test1', 'test2'] This works fine
          return companiesFinal;
      }
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is working properly?

---

Here is an example of the object array returned from my PHP script. Objects with IDs 1 and 1216 show up on the typeahead dropdown, but non of the others do. I can not see any patterns or clue as to why only these would show and not the others.

```
[
   {
      "id": "1265",
      "score": "40",
      "name": "LMV AB"
   },
   {
      "id": "10834",
      "score": "33",
      "name": "Letona"
   },
   {
      "id": "19401",
      "score": "33",
      "name": "Lewmar"
   },
   {
      "id": "7158",
      "score": "33",
      "name": "Lazersan"
   },
   {
      "id": "3364",
      "score": "33",
      "name": "Linpac"
   },
   {
      "id": "1216",
      "score": "33",
      "name": "L H Evans Limted"
   },
   {
      "id": "1",
      "score": "33",
      "name": "LH Evans Ltd"
   },
   {
      "id": "7157",
      "score": "33",
      "name": "Lazersan"
   }
]
```

And finally the array that is past in `process(companiesFinal)`:

```
["LMV AB", "Letona", "Lewmar", "Lazersan", "Linpac", "L H Evans Limted", "LH Evans Ltd", "Lazersan"]
```

---

Anyone have any clue? I am still totally clueless as to why this isn't working still :(

---

```
$('#companyNameInput').typeahead({
      source: function(query, process){

        companyTOut = setTimeout(function(){
          return $.ajax({
            url: ROOT+'Record/checkCompanyName',
            data: 'q='+query,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
              var count = 0;
              var companiesFinal = [];
              map = [];
              $.each(data, function(i, v){
                map[v.name] = [v.id, v.score];
                companiesFinal.push(v.name);
              })
              process(companiesFinal);

            }
          })
        }, 250)
      },
      minLength: 2,
      highlighter: function(item)
      {
        $('#companyNameInput').closest('.control-group').removeClass('success')
        companyLocked = false;
        return '<span class="unselectable" title="'+map[item].score+'">'+item+'</span>';
      },
      updater: function(item)
      {
        selectedEntityId = map[item][0];
        selectedCountryScore = map[item][1];
        lockCompany(selectedEntityId);
        return item;
      }
    });
```

---

```
$output .= '['.$output;
    foreach($results as $result) {
      $output .= '{"id":"'.$result['id'].'",';
      $output .= '"score":"'.$result['score'].'",';
      $output .= '"name":'.json_encode($result['name']).'},';
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo substr($output, 0, strlen($output)-1).']';
```

---

Console output for "parm":

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
id: "25024"
name: "part"
score: "75"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
id: "15693"
name: "pari"
score: "75"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
id: "28079"
name: "Pato"
score: "50"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
id: "18001"
name: "PASS"
score: "50"
__proto__: Object
4: Object
id: "15095"
name: "PSR"
score: "33"
__proto__: Object
5: Object
id: "22662"
name: "PRP"
score: "33"
__proto__: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: No sack to justify down-vote?

Comment: I experimented a bit more and found out that selecting an item from the drop down list with the mouse does not always work, resulting in similar behavior you describe. Could you check if it helps if you select items using the `up`, `down` and `enter` keys?

Comment: @Marijn The problem is, is that there are only one or two items in the dropdown when there should be many so there isn't much to select with the arrow keys :(

Comment: hmmm ... could you insert `console.log(data)` in the first line of you success function to (again) confirm that the correct data is returned?

Comment: @Marijn Please see edit for console output.

Comment: Ah, think I got it now. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

#### Update 2

Ah, your service returns items that actually don't match the query `parm`. Your typeahead query is `'parm'`, with which none of the returned results match. You can override the `matcher` function used by the typeahead plugin, see the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead). Simply implement it as `return true` to match all results returned by your service.

#### Update 1

This is an updated version, that maps the name to an  id, which can be used later. A [jsfiddle is available](http://jsfiddle.net/serra/w93aR/16/).

```
var nameIdMap = {};

$('#lookup').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: lookupUrl,
            data: getAjaxRequestData(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (json) {
                process(getOptionsFromJson(json));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    updater: function (item) {
        console.log('selected id'+nameIdMap[item]);
        return item;
    }
});

function getOptionsFromJson(json) {
    $.each(json, function (i, v) {
        nameIdMap[v.name] = v.id;
    });

    return $.map(json, function (n, i) {
        return n.name;
    });
}
```

#### Original answer

You need to make the call async and call the `process` callback from within the success callback like this:

```
$('#companyNameInput').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ROOT + 'Record/checkCompanyName',
            // async: false, // better go async
            data: 'q=' + query,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var companiesFinal = ... // snip
                process(companiesFinal);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

The `return ['test1', 'test2'];` works, because the source function is then basically set to:

```
// do ajax stuff, but do nothing with the result
// return the typeahead array, which the typeahead will accept as the result:
return ['test1', 'test2'];
```

*Notes*

There is a one-liner to fill `companiesData`:

```
var companiesFinal = return $.map(data, function (n, i) { n.name; });
```

And you probably want to declare your variables using `var`; otherwise they'll have global scope, which will bite you.

Comment: I moved the process into the success callback of the ajax function but I am still getting exactly the same results :( Please see edit for updated version.

Comment: Is the response type of your PHP method set to application/Json?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the answer to show you the part that builds the JSON.

Comment: I have some difficultites understanding your javascript code, but I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serra/w93aR/16/) for you that I *think* does what you need, namely fetch the typeahead data async and match the selected item to its corresponding id. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you that did it! Something so small. Here are your 50 love points :D

Comment: I guess this use case was slightly unusual as it's more like a nearest matcher not a typeahead. Uses levenshtein etc to return the matches in my PHP script together with some other bits and bobs.

Comment: Actually, I think your question is exactly the kind of scenario for which the custom `matcher` function is intended. The pass-all matcher from our solution is a perfect match for smart, server side autocompletion. BTW, you might be interested in the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) library too. I used that with twitter bootstrap in a similar scenario.