# Bootstrap tagsinput and typeahead with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using Bootstrap `tagsinput` and `typeahead`, which works perfectly when I use it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tagsinput-typeahead').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: $.getJSON('/ajax/tags.php'),
            afterSelect: function() {
                this.$element[0].value = '';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But I want to use it with *ajax*, but it only shows me the first letter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    jQuery('.tagsinput-typeahead').tagsinput({
        typeahead : {
            source: function (query, process) {
                return jQuery.get('/ajax/tags.php?query=' + query, function(data){  
                // return process(data);              
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Even when I return `process(data);` it won't work.

In addition when I click on *one suggestion* the letter will appear in the inputfield as well.

[image: picture]

My `tags.php` looks like this:

```
$json = [];
$json[] = "test";
$json[] = 'Washington';
$json[] = 'London';
$json[] = 'Germany';
$json[] = 'Denmark';
echo json_encode($json);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hope this will help you [Bootstrap Typeahead with AJAX source: not returning array as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402768/bootstrap-typeahead-with-ajax-source-not-returning-array-as-expected). Which Bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think I'm using bootstrap 3.